# phpMyAdmin error: #2005 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I receive the following error when trying to login to MySQL using phpMyAdmin:

## 2005 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

What I am trying to setup is a phpMyAdmin login page with multiple servers in a drop down menu, and blank fields for username/password so that users can login to any of the servers with any valid account they possess.

When I try to login I get the error, but no traffic reaches the MySQL server (tested using tcpdump).

I have eliminated account issues (I can login using the account information via CLI, or if I change the phpMyAdmin settings to allow an empty server field rather than a drop down menu).  The login only fails when attempting to use a drop down server menu.

Here is the config.inc.php I am using:

```
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
//$cfg['LeftDisplayServers'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
//$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;
$cfg['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '<MySQL DEV>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '<servername1withfqdn>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|performance_schema)';

$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '<MySQL UAT>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '<servername2>';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|performance_schema)';

?>
```

Do I have a configuration error I have overlooked?